# Strange copper wire on CO2 Laser Tube

Tags: laser

[image]

[image]

I just purchased a 40W CO<sub>2</sub> Laser Tube.

I noticed there is a weird stray copper wire coming out from the negative anode that is looped and tied around the lens frame. Can anyone explain what this is and its purpose?
Is it supposed to be there, or is it a manufacturing defect?
Is it safe to have it exposed like that, do I need to “cut it off”?

Comment: don't cut it off.

Comment: Interesting, this wire is not shown on product [photos](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2334524.m570.l1313&_nkw=Cloudray+40W+CO2+laser+tube&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_odkw=40W+CO2+laser+tube&_osacat=0).

Answer (score 3):

If I were to guess I would say it has something to do with keeping the trigger voltage within spec (reducing it), something like the trigger wires on the outside of the glass of flash tubes-  photo from [rheintacho.de](https://rheintacho.de/en/products/accessories-and-spare-parts/stationary-stroboscopes/spare-parts/flash-tube-rt-strobe-3000-xenon/)

This also looks like a retro-fitted fix to reduce the trigger voltage- the bands proved to be insufficient.

[image]

It might or might not work without it, but it would increase the stress on your power supply at start-up if it wasn't there.

Answer (score 2):

In your photo the wire looks like it's glued to the surface, so it's thought to stay there. I guess it's a debug which is found to improve the function of the electric field in the gas. Inserting it afterwards, of course, looks peculiar, but surely it's found to be more cost effective than redesign - at least, if hundreds or thousands of not so perfectly designed tubes already are manufactured.

Shortly: Let it be!